# write() performs differently in two situations

Tags: c, linux, file, file-io, io

So I was required to solve this exercise:

This exercise is designed to demonstrate why the atomicity guaranteed by opening a file with the `O_APPEND` flag is necessary. Write a program that takes up to three command-line arguments:

```
$ atomic_append filename num-bytes [x]
```

This file should open the specified filename (creating it if necessary) and append `num-bytes` bytes to the file by using `write()` to write a byte at a time. By default, the program should open the file with the `O_APPEND` flag, but if a third command-line argument (x) is supplied, then the `O_APPEND` flag should be omitted, and instead the program should perform an `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)` call before each `write()`. Run two instances of this program at the same time without the `x` argument to write 1 million bytes to the same file:

```
$ atomic_append f1 1000000 & atomic_append f1 1000000
```

Repeat the same steps, writing to a different file, but this time specifying the `x` argument:

```
$ atomic_append f2 1000000 x & atomic_append f2 1000000 x
```

List the sizes of the files f1 and f2 using `ls –l` and explain the difference.

So this is what I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int fd, flags, num_bytes;
        if (argc < 3 || strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0) {
                printf("Usage: %s filename num-bytes [x]\n", argv[0]);
                return 1;
        }
        num_bytes = atoi(argv[2]);
        if (argc == 4 && strcmp(argv[3], "x") == 0) {
                fd = open(argv[1], O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0666);
                if (fd == -1)
                        perror("open");
                while (num_bytes-- > 0) {
                        lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
                        write(fd, "a", 1);
                }
                if (close(fd) == -1)
                        perror("close");
        }
        else {
                fd = open(argv[1], O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_WRONLY, 0666);
                if (fd == -1)
                        perror("open");
                while(num_bytes-- > 0)
                        write(fd, "a", 1);
                if (close(fd) == -1)
                        perror("close");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Now after I ran it as required:

```
abhinav@cr33p:~/System/5$ ./a.out f1 1000000 & ./a.out f1 1000000
[1] 4335
[1]+  Done                    ./a.out f1 1000000
abhinav@cr33p:~/System/5$ ./a.out f2 1000000 x & ./a.out f2 1000000 x
[1] 4352
[1]+  Done                    ./a.out f2 1000000 x
abhinav@cr33p:~/System/5$ ls f1 f2
f1  f2
abhinav@cr33p:~/System/5$ ls -l f*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 abhinav abhinav 2000000 Dec 10 16:23 f1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 abhinav abhinav 1000593 Dec 10 16:24 f2
```

Definitely, there is a difference in file sizes I am somewhat unable to clearly understand why? I searched and found somewhere this explanation:

> The sizes were definitely different:

```
-rw------- 1 posborne posborne 1272426 2012-01-15 21:31 test2.txt
-rw------- 1 posborne posborne 2000000 2012-01-15 21:29 test.txt
```

> Where test2.txt was run without O_APPEND. test2.txt is short by the
>   number of times (or bytes as a result of times) that seeking to the
>   end of the file did not happen at the same time as the write (quite
>   frequently).

But it does not seem to make any sense. So why the difference in sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code, run on a file not opened with `O_APPEND`:

```
            while (num_bytes-- > 0) {
                    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
                    write(fd, "a", 1);
```

writes to the location of the *end of the file as it was when the call to `lseek()` was made*.  The end of the file can change in the time between the `lseek()` and `write()` call.

This code, on a file that was opened with `O_APPEND`:

```
            while(num_bytes-- > 0)
                    write(fd, "a", 1);
```

is *guaranteed* by the standard behavior of `write()`'ing to a file opened with `O_APPEND` to write to the end of the file *no matter where that end is*.

That's the entire point of the `O_APPEND` flag - `lseek()` then `write()` *doesn't work*.

Comment: How can the end of file change in between those two calls when before `write()` with the help of `lseek()` the end of file is being updated? Aren't they atomic?

Comment: `lseek()` is one call.  `write()` is another.  The sequence `lseek(); write();` is two separate calls - and the two do not work atomically.  And the end of the file can change between those two calls.  Again - that's <I>why</I> the `O_APPEND` flag exists.